# IBM Bluemix SQL Database service data store management

Tags: sql, database, ibm-cloud

I'm working on IBM Bluemix SQL Database service with premium plan. According to our application the sql service can have many schemas.

Is there any way to seperate data storage of each schema to different physical storage and manage them as individual(file, file group etc.)

For example:  The tables and data on SchemaUser1 stored in SQLDBFile1 and SchemaUser2's tables and data stored in SQLDBFile2 
Is it possible to create schemas like this? or the only way to separate datastore is creating a new sql database service.

Comment: You should post this question in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the background of the question, why do you want to separate the storage in that virtual environment? The DB2 on Cloud service offers more management options as it is only a hosted, not a fully managed service.

Comment: Actually It's not clear now its really needed but I just want to learn it is possible or not. each partner will have different schema and the schema will be created automatically on demand programmatically in our application. Therefore, it may cause a security or authentication problem between different partner's schemas.

Answer (score 0):

With the SQLDB premium plan you can create multiple schemas within a single database. For each schema and the objects within privileges can be assigned, i.e., it is possible to manage security on  a per-schema level and for the objects within. Access to the objects (tables, views, functions, ...) is independent of their storage location (tablespaces).